# Django value doesn't load on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

Help please in my site, i used `jquery` and `django`.

In views i create a new variable :

```
strin = "2014-10-10 21:32,75\n"
```

but when i try to use it in `jquery`, them crashed, why? (P.S. there is back correct value)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var a = "{{ strin }}"
  g = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
    "Date,Value\n" + a
  );
</script>
```

also, when i simply try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  g = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
    "Date,Value\n" + "2014-10-10 21:32,75\n"
  );
</script>
```

This works.

Standart template, what i take, somethings like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  g = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
    "Date,Temperature\n" +
    "2008-05-07,75\n" +
    "2008-05-08,70\n" +
    "2008-05-09,80\n"
  );
</script>
```

I don't know why them is crashed, only jquery stoped wokring and graphs doesn't load.
Please help.

And another thing, if you know what the problem this, can you help with array values, not one.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the crash traceback. You're likely not passing the variable to the template context.

Comment: my guess is "\n" doesn't get written when using template variable. Have you seen the generated html source?

Comment: View the rendered source code using your browser and/or try pasting the same script code into a `<pre></pre>` block to make sure it is rendering valid javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think that here:

```
 var a = "{{ strin }}"
```

You should use {{ strin }} without quotes.
did you cheked if strin variable is returned from Django Server to front end?
Try to print it somwhere on front end.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can have many sources and I don't see anything related to jQuery in your question either. I'll try to guess and give some pointers on how to debug.

1. Make sure your JS code actually is parsed by Django's templating engine. Django doesn't check linked JS files or otherwise included JS code by default. Only the JS code you have inside your HTML files.
2. Make sure you attach that 'strin' variable to the context and that you pass that context to the template rendering function.

Debugging

1. Open the web console in developer tools in your browser. It will tell you where exactly the JS error lies.
2. Output that 'strin' variable directly into the HTML for testing so that you can see if it actually is the expected thing. Also do a print in your Python code. This way you can confirm the correctness from both sides. The output of your print call will show up in the console where you started your server or in your server logs, by the way.